# Does a possum pouch fall off in an antimagic field?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, antimagic-field

If a PC wearing a *possum pouch* (*Complete Adventurer* 134-5) (1,800 gp; 1 lb.) enters an [*antimagic field*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsAtoB.html#antimagic-field), is the *possum pouch* affected? Does the *pouch* detach?

I'm not sure if the *possum pouch* should work identically to a *dimensional pocket* (*Dragon* #313 56) (9,000 gp; 0 lbs.) that says that the *pocket* "cannot be removed unless the command word is spoken or the wearer dies, but contact with the extradimensional space to which the pocket is connected can be suppressed with a targeted [*dispel magic*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsDtoE.html#dispel-magic) or antimagic effect."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The magic of the *possum pouch* is the bit about adhering it to the body and hiding it. In an *antimagic field*, it would be visible and may fall off (depending on how the wearer is dressed).

This would also happen to *dimensional pockets* except that *dimensional pockets* apparently have some extra protection against suppressing that function that is fairly unique to those items. That is, the only reason that this doesn’t happen to *dimensional pockets* is because their description explicitly gives them a special exception to the usual suppression rules, which would include those properties.

On the other hand, access to a *possum pouch*’s contents would not be impeded by suppression. Unlike a *dimensional pocket*, which is less of a “pocket” and more of a magic entry-point to an extradimensional space, the *possum pouch* has no magical storage capabilities—its storage is wholly mundane and unaffected by suppressing magic.